# Headers indicative of location sourcing

Tags: http, header, location, tracking

I'm trying to write an application that runs in the background and checks if my device's location is being requested and warns me if that happens. While I don't have any issues with the script itself, i do have a question; I understand that certain websites will use certain headers that can be indicative of that website requesting my location information. I understand that 'XMLHttpRequest' is one of such headers, but i don't know how common of a header that is, and it certainly won't detect ALL such requests.

Ideally, I'm looking for a directory/repository with all headers that could be indicative of the website locating my device. The script is connected to my browser so anything my browser sees, my script sees. With a directory like that I could include all of the headers and effectively write a tracking detector.

If such directory/repository does not exist, do you know websites/posts where I could find bits and pieces? Or do you perhaps know some headers yourself? I need as much as possible.

I tried searching for a directory like that but I can't find anything/ask the question right.

Here is my script and how it works:

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

headers = ['XMLHttpRequest', 'X-Forwar']
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Check if the website is requesting location information
    if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == [x for x in headers]:
        print("WARNING: Website is requesting your location information.")

    return "Hello, World!"

http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```